# Vandermonde matrix and its binary representation

Tags: arithmetic, linear-algebra, coding-theory, error-correcting-codes

Say one is given a Vandermonde matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) of dimension $2^q \times k$ such that the elements of the first column of it are $\{0,1,2,..,-1+2^q\}$. (This then uniquely specifies the matrix). Now say one enlarges this to a matrix of dimension $2^q \times (1+q(k-1))$ over $\{0,1\}$ by replacing all the entries (except the first column) by its bit-string in binary representation.

Are there known relationships between the two matrices? 
Any easy way to relate them?
Like I believe it remains true that every subset of $k$ rows of the new matrix are also linearly independent (over $\mathbb{F}_2$?). How does one see this?

---

EDIT : In the original matrix itself assume that all arithmetic are being done "mod $2^q$" so that all entries in the Vandermonde matrix are elements of $\mathbb{F}_{2^q}$ and hence everyone has a $q-$bit representation.

Comment: Is it the full binary representation where the original last column already takes up $q(k-1)$ binary columns, or we truncate all the binary representations by modulo $2^q$? In the second case your assertion is not true.

Comment: @WillardZhan    Please see the updated EDIT. I have clarified this. Thanks1

Comment: Are you working on erasure coding?

Comment: I wasnt thinking of such a connecṭion. But if you have seen this somewhere then please share the reference!

Comment: @gradstudent The arithmetic in $\mathbb{F}_{2^q}$ and in $\mathbb{Z}/2^q\mathbb{Z}$ are different. If it is the later one which is modulo $2^q$, then a counterexample is $q=3,k=4$ and the rows corresponding to $0,2,4,6$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: And I just realized that if you are considering encoding the elements in $\mathbb{F}_{2^q}$ with $\mathbb{F}_2^q$, then using the isomorphism between their additive groups as the encoding, your assertion is directly true.

Comment: Any explanations why?

Comment: Because it can be viewed as an isomorphism between vector spaces both on $\mathbb{F}_2$. That means if the binary matrix has $\leq k$ linearly dependent rows whose sum are zero vector, the sum of these rows in the original matrix is also zero.